# How to re-render a functional component with a custom useState hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've created a custom useState hook in order to understand better the under the hood implementations of React and I've managed to create the below code:

```
import App from "../App";
import {root} from '../index';

const states : any[] = [];

let statesLastIndex = 0;

function bindState(initalState : any) {

    const currentIndex = statesLastIndex;

    const setState = (newState : any) => {
        states[currentIndex] = newState;
        root.render(App());
        statesLastIndex = 0;
    };

    states.push(initalState);

    statesLastIndex++;

    return [states[currentIndex], setState];
}

export { bindState };
```

My only problem is that on every state update I re-render the whole App component which is the main component of my application. How can I re-render the function that is calling the hook, without any additional parameters to the bindState function? Basically the question is what parameter should be added to root.render() in order to render the component that is calling the setState function?

Thanks